# IBM Worklight - How to change the default "Worklight Settings" string?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to change the default "Worklight Settings" string in Android's OptionsMenu, as provided by Worklight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: corrected the answer a bit...

Yes.

1. Open yourApp.js (located at `yourProject\apps\yourApp\common`)
2. Add the following object  before `wlCommonInit()`:

   > ```
   > WL.ClientMessages.wlSettings = "הגדרות וורקלייט";
   > ```

   - This is also mentioned in slide 8 in the [Enabling Translation training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_05_Enabling_translation.pdf).
3. (Re-)Build and deploy, launch in Android emulator or device

Worklight Settings will now look like so when translated to Hebrew:

[image]

**Some notes:**

- Make sure to change the Eclipse workspace encoding to "UTF-8" (in Eclipse Preferences > Workspace > Text file encoding). You will need to create a new Worklight project afterwards.
- If you add `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` or above to the application's AndroidManifest.xml, the OptionsMenu will not display as Google switched in this API Level to ActionBar, which is not yet available in Worklight.
- And a quick FYI to make sure you are aware that this feature is not meant for end-user consumption once moving to Production (it can fit for in-house apps to employees, but not your regular end-users; You don't want them to change the Worklight Server URL... ;).
- To better familiarize with Worklight, please go through the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).