# IBM Worklight - Can not direct update after change default "Worklight Settings" string in Android's OptionsMenu

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

After adding following object in messages.js (located at myProject/apps/myApp/common):

```
WL.ClientMessages = {
  wlSettings : "myApp settings"
};
```

Although it successfully changed from "Worklight Settings" to "myApp settings" in Android's OptionsMenu, when I look in Logcat it shows the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WL is not defined at
>   file:///data/data/com.test/files/www/default/js/messages.js:10

Also, if I trigger a Direct Update by changing a web resource, it fails with the following error:

> tag: test(my app's name)
>
> [http://192.168.1.5:10080/test/apps/services/api/test/android/composite]
>   exception. TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
>
> tag:CordovaLog
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
>
> tag: Web Console
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined at
>   file:///data/data/com.test/files/www/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js:1763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way I previously explained my answer to this question: [IBM Worklight - How to change the default "Worklight Settings" string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015776/ibm-worklight-how-to-change-the-default-worklight-settings-string)

I have corrected it.

This happens now because messages.js is not in the scope of the `WL` namespace.
By doing so it will override the whole ClientMessages object, leaving you with only one property - wlSettings. This will cause various pieces of functionality to fail, e.g. direct update failure you're experiencing is caused by the fact that WL framework cannot retrieve the required message string.

Move the object from messages.js to yourApp.js, above `wlCommonInit()`, and update it like this:

```
/* myApp.js 
...
...
/*

WL.ClientMessages.wlSettings = "myApp Settings";

function wlCommonInit() {
    ...
    ...
}
```